# Need help in graphing on Mathematica 10

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, alpha, graphing

What do I type in if I want to graph `tan (x^y) = tan (y^x)`? I've tried `Plot[Tan x^y = Tan y^x, {y, x, 0, 5}]` and several other things and it does not work.

Comment: RegionPlot might work, but id suggest you first spend some time learning basic syntax.

Comment: Worth noting that `==` and `=` are different things in Mathematica, and in many other programming languages.  And that `Tan x^y` does not apply the function `Tan` to the expression `x^y`, rather it multiplies the symbol `Tan` by the expression `x^y`, which is probably not what you want to do. You should, as @george advises, spend some time familiarising yourself with Mathematica's basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `ContourPlot` rather,

```
 ContourPlot[ Tan[  y^x ] == Tan[ x^y ]    , {x, 0, 5} , {y, 0, 5 } , PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

This is unfortunately picking up some false solutions where `y^x== (2 n + 1 ) Pi/2`

or you can capture *some* of the solutions faster/clearer like this:

```
 Show@
   Table[
     ContourPlot[y^x - x^y   + n Pi  == 0  , {x, 0, 5} , {y, 0, 5 } ],
   {n, -20, 20}]
```

[image]